# Is it possible to optimize these SQL queries further?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

I have a Rails app (running on a Heroku account) which is grabbing a bunch of statistics for the home page regarding the number of records which match certain criteria. Each count is displayed as a number on the page. My table (listings) consists of about 22,500 records. On production it takes the page about 350ms to load (still below the threshold but not great for a home page).

Please bear with the number of queries here, I wanted to portray the redundancy of what I'm trying to do. This *feels* like it could be done much more efficiently. Any ideas?

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('Syracuse'))
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('Syracuse')) AND (created_at >= '2011-01-30 18:28:44.656702')
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('Cicero', 'Clay', 'Lysander', 'VanBuren', 'Salina'))
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('Cicero', 'Clay', 'Lysander', 'VanBuren', 'Salina')) AND (created_at >= '2011-01-30 18:28:44.811090')
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('DeWitt', 'Manlius', 'Pompey'))
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('DeWitt', 'Manlius', 'Pompey')) AND (created_at >= '2011-01-30 18:28:44.954442')
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('Onondaga', 'Elbridge', 'Geddes', 'Camillus'))
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('Onondaga', 'Elbridge', 'Geddes', 'Camillus')) AND (created_at >= '2011-01-30 18:28:45.105438')
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('Fabius', 'Lafayette', 'Marcellus', 'Otisco', 'Skaneateles', 'Spafford', 'Tully'))
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('Fabius', 'Lafayette', 'Marcellus', 'Otisco', 'Skaneateles', 'Spafford', 'Tully')) AND (created_at >= '2011-01-30 18:28:45.258860')
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('West Monroe', 'Hastings', 'Constantia', 'Palermo', 'Mexico', 'Parish', 'Schroeppel'))
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM listings WHERE (city in ('West Monroe', 'Hastings', 'Constantia', 'Palermo', 'Mexico', 'Parish', 'Schroeppel')) AND (created_at >= '2011-01-30 18:28:45.411138')
```

One option I considered is using the after_add and after_remove hooks on my Listing model to update a separate table with these statistics. My only concern with this is the maintenance issues involved. However, new listings are only added a few times throughout the day so updating said table shouldn't cause performance issues in itself.

Thanks!

Comment: It's using the Postgres database Heroku supplies by default. I'm also using the free Heroku account (maybe the culprit?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Various approaches, not all database-oriented.

You can combine all the selects into a single query like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN city = 'Syracuse' THEN 1 END) as syracuse,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN city = 'Syracuse' AND created_at >= '2011-01-30 18:28:44.656702' THEN 1 END) as syracuse_recent,
       /* etc... */
FROM listings
```

This will be just one scan over the table to collect all the stats.

Alternatively/additionally, cache the statistics extracted from the database in memory in your application, or use something like memcached. If there's no need for the statistics to be up-to-the-minute accurate, this offloads the query from the database completely, after the initial population.

Comment: No need to put my answer in, but I was going to suggest two queries, one with the date filtered conditions and one without.  Then possibly two indexes tuned to the two queries.

Comment: If all the queries are going to cover all the table eventually (which seems likely), using an index is unlikely to be a benefit. Especially in PostgreSQL which has to reference the heap data anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this start to get a little too database gnostic with the CASE statement? Will CASE statements work across all databases?

Comment: that syntax will certainly work on PostgreSQL, SQL Server and Oracle; CASE is the ANSI standard construct to replace more db-specific functions like `decode()`, `nullif()` et al. Using `sum/count(case...)` like this is a widespread technique.

Answer (score 0):

First you should examine which indexes you have on the tables (try adding and removing indexes on individual fields and also composite indexes in both direction).

Also make sure to analyze exactly what does the 350ms compose of (with firebug or something like YSlow).

Finally if you really have rare updates and you want to maintain a summary table hooks are not the only way - you can also write trigger that will do this job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would add two new tables, one that contains groups of cities and the other a many to many link table between the groups and cities.  You would need "city_group_id", "city_group_name", "dt_count_threshold".  The second table would be "city_group_id", "city_id".  Then you can perform selects against the many to many link table and join the city table with your date/time restriction.

```
-- unrestricted count
selec cg.city_group_name, count(*) as cnt
from dbo.city_group cg
join dbo.city_group_city cgc on cg.city_group_id = cgc.city_group_id
group by city_group_name

-- restricted
selec cg.city_group_name, count(*) as cnt
from dbo.city_group cg
join dbo.city_group_city cgc on cg.city_group_id = cgc.city_group_id
join dbo.city c on c.city_id = cgc.city_id
group by city_group_name
where c.created_at >= cg.dt_count_threshold
```

Keep in mind, these are untested queries so there might be some minor adjustments needed.  And make sure all indexes are setup correctly to avoid table scans.